# Using Lambda Function in Python to generate a wavelength of numbers from -1.0 to 1.0

Tags: python, lambda, waveform

I'm using a class to store a list of floats and then using those floats to create a waveform constructed out of hashes (#).

I need to add a function that uses a lambda which can be used to replace every value with another based on the original value. For example, all values such that abs(x) < 0.5 become -1.0 or 1.0 depending on whether they were originally negative or positive.

I'm stuck on how to draw the waveform in the console in python. The waveform of numbers should look like this:

Number Hash Waveform
[image: Number Hash Waveform]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda functions in python are used in place of an actual named function for convenience and brevity so I dont know if making a function which contains a lambda function is the correct thing here.  You could add a method which acts on your list like this:

```
def transform(self):
    temp = []
    for x in self.mylist:
        if abs(x) < 0.5:
            temp.append(-1.0)
        else:
            temp.append(+1.0)
     return temp
```

alternatively you could do it 'inline' with a lambda like this:

```
lambda x: -1.0 if abs(x) < 0.5 == 0 else +1.0
```

Or better still you could use a list comprehension:

```
newList = [-1.0 if abs(x) < 0.5 else 1.0 for x in oldList]
```